# how to put exact number of decimal places on label ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

How can I specify the exact number of decimal places on `ggplot` bar chart labels?

The data:

```
strefa  <- c(1:13)
a       <- c(3.453782,3.295082,3.137755,3.333333,3.500000,3.351351,3.458824,3.318681,3.694175,3.241379,3.138298,3.309524,3.380000)
srednie <- data.frame(strefa,a)
```

The code is:

```
ggplot(srednie, aes(x=factor(strefa), y=a, label=round(a, digits = 2))) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity",  colour="darkgrey", width = 0.5) +
  theme(legend.position="none",axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(size = 4, hjust = 1.2) +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(1,6))+
  xlab("") +
  ylab("")
```

As you can see, on bars entitled 5 and 2 the labels are limited to the 1st decimal place. How to show 2 decimal places even if there is i.e. 3.000000 or 5.999999? In such a cases I would like to show 3.00 and 6.00.

I tried to use as a `aes` parameter `label=round(a, digits = 2)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could try the following as it rounds to two digits and prints two digits after the decimal.

```
ggplot(srednie, aes(x=factor(strefa), y=a, label=sprintf("%0.2f", round(a, digits = 2)))) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity",  colour="darkgrey", width = 0.5) +
  theme(legend.position="none",axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(size = 4, hjust = 1.2) +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(1,6))+
  xlab("") +
  ylab("")
```

The only modification was changing your code from

```
round(a, digits = 2)
```

to

```
sprintf("%0.2f", round(a, digits = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want just 3 digits no matter of the decimals?  123.45 -> 123, 1.234 -> 1.23,  0.0121  ->  0.01,  1 -> 1.00

Comment: @skan what do you want if the input is `1234567.89` ? There are 7 digits before `.`.

Comment: :) Numbers that big don't happen in my problem. In that case I would write it with scientific format.  Finally I'm using the function substr(mynumbers, 1, 4)

Comment: @skan with `substr` you may have incorrect rounding at the third digit (`1.239` would become `1.23` instead of `1.24`). Something like the following would get past that `threeDigits <- function(innums, max.digit.count = 3) {
    ld <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(innums), "[.]"), function(x) nchar(x[1]))
    newnums <- round(innums, max.digit.count - ld)
    fmtList <- paste0("%0.", max.digit.count - ld, "f")
    sapply(1:length(fmtList), function(x) sprintf(fmtList[x], newnums[x]))
}`