# How do you round digits for labels on a barplot chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, rounding, digits

I want to round to 2 digits my labels in the bars.

```
labs(x="Emisora", y="Rend. pot. 2019") +
  geom_text(aes(label=upside), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10, face="bold")) +
```

My labeles has 9 digits, like 23.945678909 and I want 23.95 or 23.96

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369855/how-to-put-exact-number-of-decimal-places-on-label-ggplot-bar-chart

Comment: `labs(x="Emisora", y="Rend. pot. 2019") +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(upside, digits = 2)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10, face="bold"))`

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm learning to use R and ggplot. It works very well! Thank you.