# How to control decimal places for value labels in bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, decimal, bar-chart, stacked-chart

Consider the figure below:

[image]

This question is about how to keep all the value labels in the stacked bars in one decimal place, to allow for consistency. Thus, to present -1, 2 and 5 as -1.0, 2.0 and 5.0 in line with others. Here is an example data

```
df  <- data.frame(group=c("satisfied", "satisfied",
                      "unsatisfied","unsatisfied",
                      "satisfied", "satisfied", 
                      "unsatisfied","unsatisfied"
                      ), 
                cost=c("low","high","low","high",
                      "low","high","low","high"),     
                treatment=c("treated","treated","treated","treated",
                            "untreated","untreated",
                      "untreated","untreated") ,
                value=c(2.3,8.7,5.0,3.1,9.4,3.1,2.0,-1.0))
```

and the code for generating the figure is

```
#REORDER
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = c("satisfied", 
                            "unsatisfied"))

ggplot(data=df,aes(y = value, x = group, fill = cost)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity",position='stack') + 
ylab("Y label") +
theme(legend.direction = "horizontal",legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.1, 'cm'))+
theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(value !=0, value, "")), 
         position = position_stack(vjust=0.5))+
facet_grid( ~ treatment)
```

Following [how to put exact number of decimal places on label ggplot bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369855/how-to-put-exact-number-of-decimal-places-on-label-ggplot-bar-chart) I attempted to resolve this by introducing

```
sprintf("%0.1f", round(value, digits = 2))
```

into the ggplot function, but this does not produce the desired output. I greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you rounded (and thus converted to `character`, losing numeric information) *before* using `sprintf`. To format numbers, you need to give `sprintf` numbers, not strings. It will take care of the rounding itself. Try this:

```
label = ifelse(value !=0, sprintf("%0.1f", value), "")
```

Making the whole code:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(y = value, x = group, fill = cost)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'stack') +
  ylab("Y label") +
  theme(
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.1, 'cm')
  ) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(value !=0, sprintf("%0.1f", value), "")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_grid(~ treatment)
```

[image]

---

The above is a little weird because of the `ifelse`. A more standard `ggplot2` solution would have you get rid of the 0s another way - maybe filter it out before plotting, give `data = filter(df, y != 0)` to `ggplot()`. Then you can use the `scales` functions

```
label = scales::label_number(accuracy = 0.1)(value)
```

Making the whole code as below, for the same result:

```
ggplot(data = dplyr::filter(df, value != 0), aes(y = value, x = group, fill = cost)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'stack') +
  ylab("Y label") +
  theme(
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.1, 'cm')
  ) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::label_number(accuracy = 0.1)(value)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_grid(~ treatment)
```

Comment: Really? Try in a fresh R session using your sample data. It works just fine for me.