# Limit the decimals in histogram labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add data label on a histogram but would like to see limited decimal. Current code is as below:

```
label =  after_stat(scales::percent(cumsum((count / sum(count))))))
```

It works fine, but returns different number of decimals depending chart variable data plotted.

Then I referred this link:
[how to put exact number of decimal places on label ggplot bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369855/how-to-put-exact-number-of-decimal-places-on-label-ggplot-bar-chart) and modified code as below:

```
   label =  after_stat(sprintf("%0.f",round(scales::percent(cumsum((count / sum(count)))),digits=2)))
```

Error in round(scales::percent(cumsum((count/sum(count))))) :
non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Can you please suggest right way to trim/round decimal to say 2 places?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass "accuracy" to `scales::percent`, e.g.

```
library(scales)
count = seq(0, 10, 1)
label = scales::percent(cumsum((count / sum(count))), accuracy = 0.001)
label
>[1] "0.000%"   "1.818%"   "5.455%"   "10.909%"  "18.182%" 
>[6] "27.273%"  "38.182%"  "50.909%"  "65.455%"  "81.818%" 
>[11] "100.000%"

label = scales::percent(cumsum((count / sum(count))), accuracy = 0.01)
label
>[1] "0.00%"   "1.82%"   "5.45%"   "10.91%"  "18.18%" 
>[6] "27.27%"  "38.18%"  "50.91%"  "65.45%"  "81.82%" 
>[11] "100.00%"
```

So, with your data, I think this should work:

```
label =  after_stat(scales::percent(cumsum((count / sum(count))), accuracy = 0.01))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I tried earlier Accuracy1L, but I do not know the difference.