# Adding exact number of decimal places in a legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Update.**  With thanks of Limey in the comment below, the solution involved adding the sprintf within the scale_fill_viridis_c command, see code below.  The original question:  This is a simple problem that I have  not managed to solve. I would like to have 2 decimal digits after the decimal point in the ggplot legend and not 6 as now (see figure below).   I have looked at answers at stack overflow (e.g.   [how to put exact number of decimal places on label ggplot bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369855/how-to-put-exact-number-of-decimal-places-on-label-ggplot-bar-chart))  but for some reasons, the solutions there do not seem to work in my case. I have e.g. tried using:
label=sprintf("%0.2f", round(c.t, digits = 2))))
and
geom_text(aes(label = round(c.t, digits = 2)))

e.g.  ggplot(aes(lon, lat, fill = c.t, label=sprintf("%0.2f", round(c.t, digits = 2))))

Please inform me if it is needed to post segment of the data to make it fully reproducible.

[image: Legend with log transformed number with 6 decimal digits]

```
 `library(geo) 
library(tidyverse)
Polychaeta<-Polychaeta%>% 
  dplyr::mutate(lon = geo::sr2d(grid_small.grid)$lon,
                lat = geo::sr2d(grid_small.grid)$lat) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat, fill = c.t)) +
  ggtitle("a. Polychaeta")+
  labs(fill= "Tonnes")+
  theme_void() +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_polygon(data = geo::island, fill = "grey") +
  coord_quickmap() +
 scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "B", direction = -1, trans="log", label = function(x) sprintf("%.2f", x))`
```

Comment: `sprintf` is the way to go, but use it in the `labels` argument to `scale_fill_viridis_c`.  [`labels` is documented under `continuous_scale`, so it's a little hard to find.]

Comment: Hi Limey thanks for your help   I just solved it as:    label = function(x) sprintf("%.2f", x))   i.e    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "B", direction = -1, trans="log", label = function(x) sprintf("%.2f", x))

Comment: Great!  That's sorted then. :=)

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I added the solution here above, in case if it may be useful for someone else.